# How to not continually repeat a background scenario for Cucumber features that depend on that background scenario

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber

I'm writing some end-to-end tests for my application using Cucumber and Selenium. I'm keeping every scenario totally independent of one another, as advised on the Cucumber website. However, my application has session based authentication, so every time a new scenario is run, it will required a login process in order to first access the site. Right now my approach is to put the login scenario as a background scenario for all other scenarios, like so:

```
  Background: User is Logged In
    Given I am on the login screen
    When I enter my login details
    And I click submit
    Then I should be logged in
```

However, this feels like a lot of duplicated 'code'. Moreover, having each scenario run independently requires a new WebDriver instance being created and a browser being run for each scenario, which feels a bit inefficient?

Can anyone advise firstly on how I can avoid duplicating the background scenario in every other scenario (if possible)  and secondly if having a separate WebDriver instance for each scenario is the correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

First of all each of your scenarios is going to have to login and create a new session. Thats the price you pay to do end to end testing. The cost of this in runtime should be relatively small with a standard login process as most login screens are simple, and have short rendering times and very little db access. It really is a very bad idea to tray and save runtime here by trying to share sessions between scenarios.

To start tidying your cukes you could follow Daniel's answer, but instead of nesting the steps I would recommend extracting the code to a helper method and calling that instead.

To do this elegantly with power, i.e. deal with different users with roles and extra attributes you need to do a bit more. You can see a detailed example of this here (https://github.com/diabolo/cuke_up).

To use this effectively follow the commit history and focus mostly on the features folder.

This has some framework code that allows you to register/create users and then use them in lots of different configurations. There is some underlying code that is a little complex, which gives you the power to create users who know their own passwords, as well as add other attributes like roles.

The end result is that you can write a step definitions like

```
Given I am registered
Given I am an admin
Given I am logged in
Given I am logged in as an admin
```

which are implemented as

```
Given 'I am registered' do
  @i = create_user
end

Given 'I am an admin' do
  @i = create_user role: 'admin'
end

Given 'I am logged in' do
  @i = create_user
  login as: @i
end

Given 'I am logged in as an admin' do
  @i = create_user role: 'admin'
  login as: @i
end
```

*note: the variable @i is used to pass the user from one step to the next*

You don't have to worry about repetition here as all the steps make calls to the same helper methods. You can use the patterns shown here in a much wider context to simplify your features/

Answer (score -1):

This example is in Ruby. You can group up the steps used for Login in `login_steps.rb` file.

In the `.feature` file you'll need to write a step like "*Given the user is logged in*". You can pass in login data in this step as well, if you want. Then in the `login_steps.rb` file, you create:

```
Given(/^the user is logged in$/) do
  step('I am on the login screen')
  step('I enter my login details')
  step('I click submit')
  step('I should be logged in')
end
```

I'm sure you can find the equivalent in any other language. Now you can write a the background like:

```
Background: Given the user is logged in
```

and it will be used before each scenario of that specific `.feature` file

As for the Webdriver, as far as I'm aware, you create a session when the test starts and you quit when it ends.

Hope it helps!

Comment: don't nest steps, instead extract stuff to a helper method and call that instead.

Comment: @diabolist, mind expanding on that ? There are multiple ways of doing this, including writing a step that doesn't nest and contains the login logic as well as writing a helper method. Try to be more clear when telling people what not to do by explaining why.

Comment: Sure: step definitions are just methods with really ugly signatures. What `step('foo') does is just use a method `step` to make a call to another method (which just happens to be a step def). Replacing this with a direct method call is equivalent and simpler.  If you extract the contents of the step `foo` into a helper method you can then use the same call in both step definitions which removes lots of complexity and makes the method chain easier to follow.

Comment: The problems with step really start happening when you end up with nesting, i.e. you have a step def that uses step that calls another step def that uses step. Now it gets really hard to follow whats happening and you end up with side effects that break scenarios. Extracting methods and calling them directly is much simpler and you can use all the standard code refactoring and organisation tools we have to make these methods simple and powerful whilst taking all the code out of your step defintions which now just act as simple intermediaries between scenario and implementation.

Comment: No sure about "really hard to follow" but thanks for your input.

Comment: step defs are harder to follow than normal methods because their method signatures are more complex and less searchable. Particularly if you have lots of params and use regex's. Its a small difference that builds when you have more stepdefs and more nesting. Having experience of de nesting stuff that was 7 or more levels deep I can assure you nesting can easily become really hard to follow. :)

Comment: It's not the case for what the question asks. I agree with you that nesting 7 levels deep is not advisable, especially if you have regex. However, for the simple background step of login I believe you can go with whatever you think is simplest and easiest for you, being a tag or step or helper method. :)

Comment: sure, my argument is that any nesting will eventually end up with deep levels of nesting, so you might as well always avoid it, especially as using helper methods has many additional benefits and few detriments.